# How can i save a file response with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, django

I have a django response sending a file to the user, which then is just ignored by the browser. How can i open a filesave dialog to save it instead?

Here is my Django code:

```
mimetype = "application/x-unknown"
file = somefilefromthedatabase

response = HttpResponse(file, mimetype=mimetype)
response["Content-Disposition"]= "attachment; filename=%s" % os.path.split(file.name)[1]

return response
```

When i access the view generating this directly, it saves the file to the database. When accessing it via jquery, nothing happens. jscode is here:

```
$(".jp-download").click(function(){
    current=$("#download").data('current').find('.id').text();
    $.post('/actions/',{action:'download',item:current});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get it to download, you'll need to pass the right headers, and set the actual page location to the new address, as if you were changing page properly.

I don't think you can initiate a download via an AJAX call.  It won't change page anyway if it starts a download.

Either put the parameters as a GET call, or create a form and submit it.

```
window.location = '/actions/?action=download&item=' + current;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to navigate to that URL by setting `window.location` to trigger a normal download.
You cannot trigger a download via AJAX.